# Removing references to Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration, gatsby

How can I safely remove all references to Gatsby in a Gatsby-built static site?

For example, the default `html.js` (in `.cache/default-html.js`) contains:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

export default function HTML(props) {
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        {props.headComponents}
      </head>
      <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <noscript key="noscript" id="gatsby-noscript">
          This app works best with JavaScript enabled.
        </noscript>
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {props.postBodyComponents}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}
```

And this results in `<div id="___gatsby"><div style="outline:none" tabindex="-1" role="group" id="gatsby-focus-wrapper">` in the source code of each of my pages.

I want to remove the string `gatsby` from all of my pages that is included by default (and not ones where I explicitly add it in - for example, I might add `<div>This site was built by gatsby</div>` to the page footer).

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, you *can* [customize html.js](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/) to edit the HTML outside of the core Gatsby application.

However this might not help you because it also states that

> Inside your `<body>` you must have a div with an id of `___gatsby`